# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop

I am new to PHP and I am trying to set up a CMS (content management system) using object oriented programming.

While re-factoring the code to make it simpler, I ran into an issue.

When I instantiate a class and call a function using the "auto 
instantiation", my array no longer works and comes back empty.

If I use the long form, it comes back with an array, but as I develop a real site this will become extremely time consuming to code this way.

Kind of lost, any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

users.php:

```
<?php

class User
{

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

    public static function find_all_users()
    {
        self::find_this_query("SELECT * FROM users");
    }

    public static function find_user_by_id($user_id)
    {
        global $database;
        $result_set = self::find_this_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$user_id LIMIT 1");
        $found_user = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);

        return $found_user;
    }

    public static function find_this_query($sql)
    {
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query($sql);
        $the_object_array = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
            $the_object_array[] = self::instantation($row);
        }

        return $the_object_array;
    }

    public static function instantation($the_record)
    {
        $the_object = new self;
//Long form instantation
        // $the_object->id      = $found_user['id'];
        // $the_object->username    = $found_user['username'];
        // $the_object->password    = $found_user['password'];
        // $the_object->first_name = $found_user['first_name'];
        // $the_object->last_name   = $found_user['last_name'];
//Auto instantation
        foreach ($the_record as $the_attribute => $value) {
            if ($the_object->has_the_attribute($the_attribute)) {
                $the_object->$the_attribute = $value;
            }
        }
        return $the_object;

    }

    private function has_the_attribute($the_attribute)
    {
        $object_properties = get_object_vars($this);
        return array_key_exists($the_attribute, $object_properties);
    }
}
//Problem is in the function???

?>
```

admin_content.php:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Page Heading -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">
            ADMIN
            <small>Subheading</small>
        </h1>

        <?php
            $users = User::find_all_users();

            if(is_object($users)) {
                foreach ($users as $user => $value) {
                    echo $user->username;
                }
            } else {
                echo "not working";
            }
        ?>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>  <a href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <i class="fa fa-file"></i> Blank Page
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Where error happens exactly? What's the value of `$users`?

Comment: There are a couple of `foreach` loops here?  What specifically is failing, and what are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: all of the comments lead to the build up of the "auto" class. Meaning, I those were previous tests.

Comment: When I check to see if the "users" is an array, it comes back empty, and I do not understand why. When I run it with out the if statement, it comes back as an invalid argument.

Comment: `admin_content.php`: This looks odd: `foreach ($users as $user => $value) {...`.  should it be: `as $arrayIndex => $user)...`?. Debugging: `var_dump($value);` I suspect you will see the user object in there.

Comment: For one, `User::find_all_users` doesn't **`return`** anything.

Answer (score 0):

Double check this part: `if ($the_object->has_the_attribute($the_attribute))`. You should not be able to access the 'has_the_attribute' private function from outside the object.

Having said that, if you're trying to apply OOP concepts to your project you should start by separating concerns in your classes. This `Users` class is clearly doing too many things. It's representing a User entity (or a collection of them), it's acting as a Repository and also as a Factory.

You should try to split those things appart, which will make it much easier to reason about your code. Some ideas:

- **User**: This object would represent what you call a user, and should have its properties as *private* and only provide accessors methods for those operations that are allowed on it to provide `encapsulation`. You could provide its mandatory data through its constructor as well.
- **UserRepository**: Would provide a couple of methods to retrieve User objects from your Database (`findAll()` and `findById`). You'd be using this from your controllers or services to fetch users from whichever data store they are in (in your case, the database).
- **UserFactory**: This class's responsibility would be to construct user objects from arrays returned from your query. It would be a dependency of your UserRepository and would contain methods like: `buildOneFromArray` (for a single DB result) or `buildFromArray` (for many DB results). It'd be used from the Repository.

Hope this helps

Comment: by the way - how do you usually cope with updating objects -create a new class for updating?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "updating". If you're referring to the model, it might not be needed if your class provides already the functionality (ie. User->changeAddress(Address $address)). You might need a particular service which coordinates a bigger change in your model. If you're referring to the data store, you can use your Repository too (UserRepository->store($user)).

Comment: I mean for instanse, if I have an Item model which has a lot of images. If I later decide to remove some images and add new images, which class method would it be better to invoke? Should I call a repository?

Answer (score 0):

you've forgotten to put `return` on that `find_all_users` function:

```
public static function find_all_users()
{
    return self::find_this_query("SELECT * FROM users");
}
```